# How to give two condition in foreach

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two condition to insert value in db but it overwrite the condition.

```
<?
  foreach($_POST['check'] as $value )
  foreach($_POST['check2'] as $value2)      
  { 
  mysql_query("insert into tb_recived_jobs set job_id='$value'emp_id='$value2'");  
  }     
?>
```

Thanks for great help

Comment: Make use of a `for` instead of `foreach`

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Should use `while`, what if elements are dynamic?

Comment: it's a little off topic but I suggest reading this: http://bobby-tables.com/ also you have tagged your question with mysqli but your code example uses the mysql lib rather than mysqli, so I've removed that tag. you can retag it if you update your code.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that `mysql` may not be the way to go, and you should use `for` or `while` as pointed out in the comments. I can see a syntax error.

```
foreach(($_POST['check'] as $value )&& ($_POST['check'] as $value2)
```

should be

```
foreach(($_POST['check'] as $value )&& ($_POST['check'] as $value2))
```

You forgot to close the `')'` from the foreach.

Comment: this made error my code : foreach(($_POST['dates'] as $val) &&($_POST['fee'] as $val1))